# How to add new field in billing address in magento 2 and how to save that attribute data?

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-attributes, billing-address

I wanted to add second field for telephone number. Can anyone tell me what is exact process for that ? Do I have to create attribute for customer address or any other ? please let me know.

Actually, I wanted to display second mobile number field in billing address form in checkout also it should display in backend where billing address is coming. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-customer-custom-attribute-in-magento-2-0/

Comment: Thanks for comment. Actually this is for creating new customer attribute. Actaully I want to add new attribute in billing address can you please tell me how can I do that ?

Comment: I am still waiting for some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for the same info and I found that Magento has something similar in their documentation:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Maybe this could help you or help someone else.

Greetings.

Comment: Unfortunately this only covers adding a field to the shipping and not the billing address.